# jQuery Slider jumps unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this script:

```
<div style="position:relative ;overflow:hidden ; height:195px;">
    <div style="position:absolute" class="scroll">
    {foreach from=$announce_list item=a}
        <div>
        <img src="imgsize.php?w=214&h=100&img=../uploads/announce/{$a.--------}.jpg"  />
        <h4 dir="rtl" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">{$a.------}</h4>
        <p dir="rtl" style="text-align:justify ;line-height:17px;">{$a.---------|truncate:"300":"..." }</p>
        </div>
    {/foreach}
    </div>
</div>
{literal}
    <script>
        $(function(){
            function change_announce()
            {
                console.log('asdasdasd');
                var Scroll = $('.scroll') ;
                Scroll.children('div:first').animate({marginTop:'-195px' } , 1000 , 
                function(){
                    Scroll.children('div:first').appendTo(Scroll).css('marginTop' , '0px' ).fadeIn(2000); 
                }
                ); 

            }
            setInterval(change_announce , 3000) ;
        });
    </script>
{/literal}
```

On this page in right pane of the site [www.mahestan.ac.ir](http://www.mahestan.ac.ir) in this demonstration the animation is not completely executed after second div is hidden the next div doesn't complete the animation ad a sudden jump occurs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** On further inspection of your code, I found that the reason for the little jump. In the animation, you are scrolling the DIV to position `-195px` which is the height of the `.scroll` div.

However, you have `padding-top:10px` and `padding-bottom:5px` to take into account. For this reason, you need to add `-15px` to the number for a total of `-210px` instead of `-195px`.

Change this line:

```
Scroll.children('div:first').animate({marginTop:'-195px' } , 1000 ,
```

To:

```
Scroll.children('div:first').animate({marginTop:'-210px' } , 1000,
```